# Passar array para Modal

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho o seguinte array `$detalhes`:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [dt_detalhes] => 2016-03-09 [desc_detalhes] => Viabilidade [tp_processo] => Viabilidade [vl_protocolo] => 1234 ) 
         [1] => Array ( [dt_detalhes] => 2016-03-12 [desc_detalhes] => Sincronizado [tp_processo] => Sincronizado [vl_protocolo] => 12345 ) 
         [2] => Array ( [dt_detalhes] => 2016-03-11 [desc_detalhes] => Integrador [tp_processo] => Integrador [vl_protocolo] => 123456 ) )
```

Gostaria de passar ele para dentro de uma modal, dessa forma:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detalhes" 
data-id="<?=$linha['id_processo']?>" data-detalhes="<?=$details?>">
```

Como posso fazer isso? Da forma tentada acima da o seguinte erro:

> Array to String Conversion

**OBS:** preciso passar o array inteiro.

Comment: Seu echo deve ser em uma chave especifica e nao no array inteiro

Comment: @rray não tem como passar o array inteiro?

Comment: Poste a estrutura completa do seu array, o que realmente quer imprimir??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `echo` serve para imprimir valores escaleres(int, string float etc) exceto arrays e objetos.

Você pode pegar o array e transforma em uma string json com o php e pelo javascript converter para um objeto.

```
<button id="button" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detalhes" 
data-id="<?=$linha['id_processo']?>" data-detalhes="<?=json_encode($detalhes);?>">
```

No javascript:

```
var data = document.getElementById('button');
var json = JSON.parse(data.getAttribute('data-detalhes'));
console.log(json);
```

Comment: postei o array completo, não tem como passar o array inteiro? tentei com o serialize data-details="<?=serialize($details)?>", passou corretamente mas como recupero ele no JQuery?

Comment: @Bia vc pegar esse array e transformar em uma string json com o php e recuperar ele através do data-attribute

Comment: eu recebo ele assim:  var details  = button.data('detalhes') no JQuery tem o equivalente ao unserialize?

Comment: @Bia editei a resposta.

Comment: retorna o erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input, verifiquei o array no JSON e ele está fechado correto com [ {  } ]

Comment: @Bia deu erro no `JSON.parse()`? vc colocou o `id` no button?

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer imprimir dados específicos do array, precisa imprimir assim:

```
echo $details[0]['dt_detalhes'];
```

Ele irá imprimir o campo `dt_detalhes` do primeiro item do array `0`

Se quiser imprimir todos os campos e todos os arrays, deve percorrelos utilizando alguma função de laço, exemplo:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($details); $i++) {
    echo $details[$i]['dt_detalhes']; // campo desejado, exemplo 'vl_protocolo'
}
```

Para entender melhor como um array funciona leia a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php), caso tenho dúvidas, poste aqui.

Comment: quero passar o array inteiro para modal através do data-attribute

Comment: esse dados (dt_detalhes, desc_detalhes, tp_processo, vl_protocolo) vão ser separados como ao serem impressos? tudo junto no mesmo campo?

Comment: vou imprimir dessa forma mesmo, mas antes gostaria de passar esses dados para uma modal específica.

Comment: Bia, realmente está um pouco confuso o que quer, dê mais detalhes, como quer mostrar essas informações, de onde vem e etc..